# DataFrame to Array of Json(keys,values)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a dataframe as below

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| columnName1 | columnName2 | columnName3 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 001         | 002         | 003         |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 004         | 005         | 006         |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to convert to JSON as expected Below Format.

EXPECTED FORMAT

```
[[{"key":"columnName1","value":"001"},{"key":"columnName2","value":"002"},{"key":"columnName1","value":"003"}],[{"key":"columnName1","value":"004"},{"key":"columnName2","value":"005"},{"key":"columnName1","value":"006"}]]
```

Thanks in Advance

I can do DF.toJSON.collect().This gives `[{"columnName1":"001","columnName2":"002","columnName3":"003"},{"columnName1":"004","columnName2":"005","columnName3":"006"}]`

But i need in expected format

Answer (score 2):

You can manually create a `json` string from given columns and `collect` as list as below

```
val json = df.columns.map(c => concat(
  lit("{\"key\": \""),
  lit(c + "\","),
  lit("\"value\": \""),
  concat(col(c), lit("\"}")))
)

df.select(array(json: _*))
  .collect()
  .map(_.getAs[Seq[String]](0).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
```

Comment: I tried this.But Still it not formatted Response. Output is coming like ```[List({"key":"columnName1","value":"001"},{"key":"columnName2","value":"002"},{"key":"columnName1","value":"003"}),List({"key":"columnName1","value":"004"},{"key":"columnName2","value":"005"},{"key":"columnName1","value":"006"})]
```

Is it possible to remove the List Key word .?

Comment: Super @shankar-koirala.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer already posted seems perfectly fine. I had to perform a bit of a tweak to make it working. Please find below!

```
val json = df.columns.map(c => concat(
lit("{\"key\": \""),
lit(c + "\","),
lit("\"value\": \""),
concat(col(c), lit("\"}")))
)

val answer = df.select(array(json: _*))
.collect()
.map(_.getAs[Seq[String]](0).mkString("[", ", ", "]")).mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
```

Check if you find this helpful!